# Integration of forms on non-simply connected manifolds

Tags: integration, analysis, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-forms

What I know is that closed forms are not exact on non-simply connected manifolds, so for instance, if $E$ is a closed form, then $dE = 0$ but $\int_\gamma E \neq 0$, where $\gamma$ is a non-contractible curve on the manifold. 
What I need to know is how to compute this integral on such a manifold. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't much else you can do other than parametrize the curve, pull the form back via the parametrization and compute the integral like usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of corrections need to be made to your statement of the problem.

First, since you're integrating over curves, you have to assume that $E$ is a $1$-form, not just any differential form.  (For $k>1$, simple connectedness is not sufficient to imply that every closed $k$-form is exact.)

Second, your statement that "if $E$ is a closed form, then $dE = 0$ but $\int_\gamma E \neq 0$, where $\gamma$ is a non-contractible curve on the manifold" is not true. Even if $\gamma$ is a non-contractible curve, there will be closed forms whose integrals over $\gamma$ are zero -- any exact form, for example.

To answer your main question: the most straightforward way to evaluate $\int_\gamma E$ is, as @Pedro said, to parametrize the curve and compute the integral directly. However, when $E$ is closed, there's another technique that can often be used to simplify the integral.  If $\sigma$ is a smooth closed curve that's homotopic to $\gamma$ (provided all the curves in the homotopy are closed curves), then $\int_\gamma E = \int_\sigma E$. Often it's possible to find a much simpler curve that's homotopic to the original one, which makes the integral easier to compute. For example, on the punctured plane, if $\gamma$ is any curve with winding number $1$ around the origin, then $\int_\gamma E$ is equal to $\int_\sigma E$, where $\sigma$ is the unit circle traversed counterclockwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistakes and also for your answer. I actually had seen the example of the punctured plane and wondered how the integral was computed. So I did the calculation for the 1-form $E=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ (which I think is really just $d\theta$) on the punctured plane & did get $2\pi$. I wanted to do the calculation for a curve trapped on a three torus (which I have no Idea what to do yet!). For a circle that goes around the axis of a torus, I did the same thing & again got $2\pi$ (taking the winding number to be 1). Did I calculate it correctly? Thank you

Comment: Plus I think a closed curve that goes around the axis of the torus and also twists around it will not be homotopic to the one I've taken to do my calculation. So I should probably take a different curve for that. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by a $3$-torus? A $3$-torus is a $3$-dimensional manifold, usually considered as a submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$.  A doughnut-shaped surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is a $2$-torus, not a $3$-torus. And what do you mean by the "axis" of a torus? Do you mean the rotation axis of some $2$-torus of revolution in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: By a 3-torus I meant $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$. (I thought a 3-torus is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$, but you say it's a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$. Am I wrong?) My goal is to do the integration on non-contractible curves on a 3-torus. I started with a 2-torus because it's easier. Yes I meant the rotation axis. Thanks.

Comment: @Fatemeh: If you have a specific question about curves on a $3$-torus, it's probably best to post it as a separate question.

Comment: Yes that's probably a better idea. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hey @JackLee, does it work also with homologous curves? I mean does the integral of a 1-form over a loop depend only on the first homology class?

Comment: @Gaff: If it's closed, yes.  The integral of a closed differential form over a smooth closed curve (or more generally over a smooth singular cycle) depends only on its homology class.

Comment: Yes, I meant closed. Thank you!